# c++ - inverted byte order when casting from char[2] to short

Tags: c++

What I have is this

```
struct Record
{
unsigned char cat;
unsigned char len[2]={0x00, 0x1b};  // can't put short here because that 
                                   // whould change the size of the struct
unsigned char dat[253];
};
Record record;
unsigned short recordlen = *((unsigned short*)record.len);
```

This result in `recordlen=0x1b00` instead of `0x001b`

Same with `*reinterpret_cast<unsigned short*>(record.len)`

Can you explain why ? How should I be doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you explain why?

Because you cannot assume a specific [*endianness*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your computer architecture.

The natural follow-up question is what do you do about it. Fortunately, you can force a specific byte order by calling one of these functions [`htonl`, `htons`, `ntohl`, or `ntohs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/htonl.html). They work regardless of the computer architecture on which you run them:

On the sending end, you convert from host order to network order; on the receiving end, you convert from network order to host order.

```
// Sending end
unsigned short recordlen = calculate_len();
*reinterpret_cast<unsigned short*>(record.len) = htons(recordlen);

// Receiving end
unsigned short recordlen = ntohs(*reinterpret_cast<unsigned short*>(record.len));
```

Answer (score 5):

What you encounter is called ["endianness"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). In x86, all numeric variables are stored "little endian", meaning the least-significant byte comes first.

From the Wikipedia page:

> The little-endian system has the property that the same value can be read from memory at different lengths without using different addresses.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on endianess of your cpu. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

In your case you have "little endian", which means that least significant bytes come first. This is convenient when you want to convert numbers to different byte sizes: if you use a long int to represent a short number, its representation is the same as if it were a short number, only it has additional zeroes at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned short recordlen = *((unsigned short*)record.len);
```

This is broken. `record.len` *doesn't* point to an `unsigned short`. Telling the compiler it does is just lying.

I presume you want:

```
unsigned short recordlen = static_cast<unsigned short>(record.len[0]) * 256 +
    static_cast<unsigned short>(record.len[1]);
```

Or, if you like it better:

```
unsigned short recordlen = (static_cast<unsigned short>(record.len[0]) << 8) |
    static_cast<unsigned short>(record.len[1]);
```

If not, code whatever it is you actually want.

Comment: already did `recordlen=record.len[0]<<8|record.len[1];`. I just wanted to know why the cast is not working well.

Comment: @WalidBaccari: It's not working well because it makes no sense. Things would be *much* worse if it seemed to work. Then your code would be broken and you might never notice until it fails when it matters!